# Let $ \ Y = \max\{X, 0\} \ $ then calculate $ \ P(Y = 0)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function of
odds
$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ $ \ $ for $-\infty < x < \infty$

Let $Y = \max\{X, 0\}$

Calculate $P(Y = 0)$

I got that $f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}e^{-|y|} & \text{if } 0 < y, \\ 0 & \text{for the rest.} \end{cases}$

So then I belive that $P(Y = 0)$ is given by all the negative y´s. Then by $f_Y(y)$ formula we know that the answer is $0$

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Pr(Y=0) = \Pr(X\le0) = \frac 1 2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

The answer is not zero.

$$\Pr(Y=0) = \Pr(X \le 0)$$

Try to observe from **symmetry** and use the fact that $X$ is a symmetric distribution to reach the conclusion.